# How to debug the salesforce app on iphone?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android, rendering

I'm working on optimizing some custom lighning components for mobile use.
On an android phone those components are rendered fine by the saleforce app, but if I open up the same components in the salesforce app on my iPhone 8, they are rendered differently.

Rendered by salesforce app on android:

[image: salesforce app on android]

Rendered by salesforce app on iPhone:

[image]

Looking like the iPhone variant of the app adding some padding to some elements.

Sadly, there's no inspector tool available for phone like in chrome on desktop which could help me find out why they are rendered differently.

Can someone explain, whats happening there?

How do you guys debug your components on salesforce app for iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried the [recommended extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.mobile_extensions_vscode_previews) for VS code?

Comment: Check [mobile debugging tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/mobile-debugging)